# set different range for tick and data points in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to show hourly data for today. So the ticks would always show 24 hours, but the real data could be just 14 or 15 hours. When I use `d3.time.scale()` and set domain as `[moment().startOf('day').toDate(), moment().endOf('day').toDate()]` and range as `[0, width - margin.left - margin.right]`, it seems that the data points are always evenly spreaded based on the x-axis, it doesn't take into account the tick position. So how to make the data points range as part of the ticks range to make sure the data points show on correct position?

Comment: Are you saying that you want ticks where the actual data points are?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Yeah, but the problem is the there are 24 ticks but only for example 16 data points, I want the data point to show where the ticks are instead of evenly speading based on the whole x-axis

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Are you saying that the x position of your data points is incorrect with respect to the axis?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, I think he's asking how to set the domain of a `d3.time.scale()` to his data min/max.

Comment: Can you check if you are using same scale for your graph and axis?